# Allowing user to hold and save video to iDevice from Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile-safari

I am trying to let my users download a video to their "Camera Roll" through my web app. You'll notice, on your iPhone, if someone sends you an mp4 file via email, you can click and hold the download icon, and an option will come up to download or "Save to your Camera Roll". Does mobile safari provide the same type of thing, and if so, what HTML has been successful for that use.

Note: I'd love to provide some code, but I can't because I haven't been able to find any documentation on this.

Thanks!